# ng-repeat orderBy - Display items as values appear in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my directive I receive through the scope an array of values which is not sorted and I would like to have it sorted with ng-repeat. Reason is there is no a special criteria for the sorting, I just want to ensure some labels are displayed in the order I desire, so a hand sorting in the link function by indexOf and splice doesn't look really good.

I wonder if creating a new array with the order I desire the labels displayed could be applied somehow in ng-repeat.

An example may help to understand my point.

My directive

`$scope.unsortedLabels // ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'] Array of labels I receive from parent directive
$scope.desiredLabelsOrder = ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2'] // The order I want the labels displayed`

My template

`<li ng-repeat="label in unsortedLabels | orderBy: ?? ></li>"`

How can I use the desiredLabelsOrder array to display the foo3 label first, then foo1 and foo2 last?

Thank you

Comment: is there a reason in which you want it that way?

Comment: The back end returns to me a bunch of labels. I can't guarantee  if they are sorted or not and if all of them exist or not. I was hoping the ng-repeat + orderBy would sort the existing labels for me as the only alternative I can think on is manually sorting the labels in the link function and I don't think that's too elegant.

Comment: so you order them by... the creation date

Comment: The order criteria must  be the chosen order to display the labels, this is reflected in desiredLabelsOrder, order them by creation time or any other criteria won't work for me.

Comment: Well, you definitely have to specify some sort criteria. Say, create an object array from the labels indicating property to sort on. Question is, why should `foo3` come before `foo1`? `ng-repeat` cannot figure that out if you cannot specify it programmatically.

Comment: you just want to order the list or leave it like its come from the server, right?

Comment: I'm not interested in sorting the list in memory. I just want to have it sorted in the view.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is weird but you can surely design it in angular by making a custom filter.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjwvfuyd/13/)

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('myFilter', function(){
    return function(items, newArrangement){
        console.log(newArrangement)
        var arrayToReturn = [];
        newArrangement.forEach(function(item,index){
            arrayToReturn[newArrangement[item-1]] = items[index];
        })

        console.log(arrayToReturn)
        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});
```

And use it in your `ng-repeat` you just have to define the new arrangement like

```
<li ng-repeat="label in unsortedLabels | myFilter: [3,1,2] ></li>
```

**Outputs**

foo3

foo1

foo2

Hope it helps.